# Volumetric Batch Normalization in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, batch-normalization

What is the tensorflow equivalent of Volumetric Batch Normalization as provided by Torch in [link](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/VolumetricBatchNormalization.lua) `nn.VolumetricBatchNormalization` ?

I am currently using:

```
output = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(input, is_training=phase_train)
```

is this the correct way of usage for inputs of dimensions `(batch_size,height,width,depth,channels)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow [`tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/batch_norm) also support volumetric batch normalization or 3D batch normalization.

Correct input dimension is `[batch, depth, height, width, in_channels]`